# My module.exports return as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios, export

I use an API to get some information I need.

```
let bodyapi = await axios.get(`www.example.com`)
```

Then I export the information I need like this:

```
const number = bodyapi.data.slice(-11);

module.exports = number
```

And then I run it on my actual file with `const number = require('./myapp.js')` (like always).

But the problem is that when I read it, it returns `[object Object]`

```
const number = require('./myapp.js')
sleep(5000) // It's a timeout function I've set, ignore it, it's just so I don't run the code too fast since it uses API''
console.log("Your ID: " + number) //Here is where it reads as [object Object]
```

Console Result:

```
Your ID: [object Object]
```

My question is: How can I fix it, so it reads what I need it to read? The bodyapi is made into an ''async'' function. I use `Axios` to read the api.

If you need more info let me know in the comments so I can edit this post. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Make sure to `console.log(number)` and it's looks like you want or not, before exports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that is correct way of exporting response from async function and using them with sleep. You should consider exporting the function like this

```
async function getResponse() {

  let bodyapi = await axios.get(`www.example.com`);
  const number = bodyapi.data.slice(-11);
  return number;
}

module.exports = getResponse;
```

Then wherver you want to use it, you can use it like this

```
const getResponse = require('./myapp.js');

getResponse()
  .then(number => console.log(number));
```

OR using async/await

```
const getResponse = require('./myapp.js');

(async() => {
   const number = await getResponse();
   console.log(number);
})();
```

Regarding it logging as [object object]. If you try concatenate an object with string you will see that behaviour.

Comment: I did both, using `.then`, I get the number as ''undefined''. Using `async` I get errors because I already use async for puppeteer on my main script.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the console log. You are stringifying your number object:
Try the following:

```
const number = require('./myapp.js')
sleep(5000) // It's a timeout function I've set, ignore it, it's just so I don't run the code too fast since it uses API''
console.log("Your ID: ", number) //
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response. Now I get "{}" as a value. Any idea why?

Comment: @Lmao123 your object is empty. you can check it by console log in your myapp.js module.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will check it out and see what's wrong with it.